# How to access couchdb cross domain from angularjs

Tags: couchdb, angularjs

I've set up a local environment, where I load data from a json file:

```js
var Players = $resource('data/players.json');
var players = Players.query(function(){});
```

And it works great.

Now I want to access a CouchDB on a different domain (http://playball.iriscouch.com/players), and based on the google buzz example I've tried the following, but I can't make it work:

```js
var Players = $resource('http://playball.iriscouch.com/players',  
  {alt: 'json', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
  {get:     {method: 'JSON'}
});

var players = Players.query(function(){});
```

I simply receive an empty array... Any ideas?

Thanks a buch!

Sune

Comment: This might help: http://kxepal.iriscouch.com/docs/1.3/features/cors.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you have control over the server, use  [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)**.

To correct your example:

```js
var Players = $resource('http://playball.iriscouch.com/players',

  // These params will be set to each request (?alt=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK),
  // where JSON_CALLBACK placeholder will be replaced with correct callback fn,
  // generated by Angular.
  {alt: 'json', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},

  // You need to configure query method to use JSONP
  {query:     {method: 'JSONP'}
});

var players = Players.query(function(){});
```

Be sure to check whether server is responding correct data (Dev Toolbar - Network panel).

Comment: so should this be as follows ?

    {query:     {method: 'JSONP'}

Comment: This is what I have been looking for all day, Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might be helpful as well: http://kxepal.iriscouch.com/docs/1.3/features/cors.html